# How to access Windows Azure ServiceBus Queue from the Windows Phone 8 application?

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

The documentation for [WindowsAzure.Messaging.Managed](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Messaging.Managed/) states the purpose of the package as:

> Use this with Windows Azure Service Bus and Notification Hubs client registration (for Windows Store and Windows Phone 8 apps). It adds Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging.Managed.dll to your project.

Unfortunately, nowhere there is a clear description on how to access the Windows Azure ServiceBus Queues mechanism from a Windows Phone 8 app.

Is there any way, at all, to access ServiceBus Queues from a Windows Phone 8 app? And if there is, which package should allow that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Notification Hubs provide all-features SDK for .Net (desktop) and device-only-features (registration management) SDKs for WP, WinRT, Android and iOS.

Azure Service Bus all-features SDK is only for .Net (desktop). But it is possible to use [REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh780717.aspx) to access basic queue/topic functionality from any platform which supports HTTP including Widows Phone.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new library that works with Windows 10, Windows 8 and many more

http://www.nuget.org/packages/AzureSBLite/ I have tested on Windows 10 and works both. Apart includes several great examples: https://github.com/ppatierno/azuresblite-examples